# Maven Spring Boot application can't find org.apache.http

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

my Spring Boot application needs to call RESTful services and I would like to use the apache `HttpClient` to do so. I added the depency to the pom.xml (tried differenct versions)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But even when I can see that the .jar-Files are downloaded during the build process:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0/httpclient-4.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0/httpclient-4.0.pom (6.0 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.0/httpcomponents-client-4.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.0/httpcomponents-client-4.0.pom (9.8 kB at 138 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0/httpclient-4.0.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0/httpclient-4.0.jar (290 kB at 1.1 MB/s)
```

But in the code I cannot access anything of it:

[image: Code Snippet]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume you're using IntellJ? What happens when you run "mvn install" from your command line?

Comment: Was the build success? If so invalidate cache and restart IntelliJ

Comment: Yes, build is always successfull but I just can't work with HttpClient when imported via maven.

Comment: In IntelliJ there’s an option to invalidate cache and restart. So that the project will get re-indexed and imports might get resolved

Comment: I will try it. The .jar files are downloaded properly, I can see them in my local repoistory. Intellij cant access them..

Comment: run forcefully "mvn -U clean install"? and update your project.

Comment: Re-Indexing did it, I can now access it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : File | Invalidate cache/ Restart else Save everything...Restart IntelliJ

Comment: That did it. Thank you!